# Circular increment of a variable x by step=1 between two files

Tags: python-3.x, increment

How can I run a circular increment  (python 3.8) of a variable x by step=1 between two files "a.py" and "b.py"? Initially x=0 in "a.py";  if "b.py" (or "a.py") executes the other file, x becomes x=1 (first increment) then when "a.py" (or "b.py") runs the other file, x becomes x=2 (second increment)  and so on until x=10.

I have tried this (unsuccessful) attempt:

b.py

```
from a import *
u=v+1;
exec(open("a.py").read());
```

a.py

```
v=0;
from b import *
v=u+1;
print(v);
exec(open("b.py").read());
```

Comment: `exec(open("a.py").read())` you really shouldn't be doing this. I makes your code extremely vulnerable to attacks.

Answer (score 0):

What you ask about is [shared values](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#shared-ctypes-objects).

But you need to re-design your app. Instead of two different files a.py and b.py you need single master file that combines both:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager

def a_worker(shared_var, *args):
    print("A", shared_var.value, args)
    shared_var.value += 1

def b_worker(shared_var, *args):
    print("B", shared_var.value, args)
    shared_var.value += 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    manager = Manager()
    var = manager.Value('i', 0) # shared variable

    print("Initial value: ", var.value)

    a_proc = Process(target=a_worker, args=(var, "a_args"))
    b_proc = Process(target=b_worker, args=(var, "b_args"))

    # Spawn processes
    a_proc.start() 
    b_proc.start()

    # Wait for processes to terminate
    a_proc.join()
    b_proc.join()

    print("After a & b finished: ", var.value)
```

Here `a_worker` and `b_worker` are the functions that implement the business logic of `a.py` and `b.py`. For more details see [Python multiprocessing library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html)

UPDATE

Ping-pong strategy. Process A increments, then process B increments, then process A increments, then ... until the shared variable reaches 10:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager, Pipe

def a_worker(shared_var, pipe):
    while shared_var.value < 10:
        print("A", shared_var.value)
        shared_var.value += 1
        pipe.send("Your turn")
        pipe.recv()
    pipe.close()

def b_worker(shared_var, pipe):
    while shared_var.value < 10:
        pipe.recv()
        print("B", shared_var.value)
        shared_var.value += 1
        pipe.send("Your turn")
    pipe.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    manager = Manager()
    var = manager.Value('i', 0) # shared variable
    a_conn, b_conn = Pipe()

    print("Initial value: ", var.value)

    a_proc = Process(target=a_worker, args=(var, a_conn))
    b_proc = Process(target=b_worker, args=(var, b_conn))

    # Spawn processes
    a_proc.start() 
    b_proc.start()

    # Wait for processes to terminate
    a_proc.join()
    b_proc.join()

    print("After a & b finished: ", var.value)
```

This program uses pipe to coordinate A and B. Process A starts, does something, then passes control to B and waits until it passes back. Process B starts waiting for A, receives a message from A, increments the variable and passes the control back.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But with your program x is incremented only from n to n+2.

Comment: Right. It was just a basic example. Extended it a little bit with passing control back and forth between A and B using pipe.